# grep two files (a.txt, b.txt) - how many lines in b.txt starts (or ends) with the words from a.txt - output: 2 files with the results

Tags: string, bash, grep, comparison

I know I ask too much, but maybe you can help with this problem too.

a.txt contains words, b.txt contains strings.

I would like to know how many string from b.txt ends with the words from a.txt

Example: 
a.txt

```
apple
peach
potato
```

b.txt

```
greenapple
bigapple
rottenapple
pinkpeach
xxlpotatoxxx
```

Output

```
3 apple greenapple bigapple rottenapple
1 peach pinkpeach
```

I would like to have a solution with grep, since it is way more faster than awk.

Can you guys please help  me?

Comment: This is a good question..no problem..don't fear to ask

Comment: The title says "starts with", but you say "ends with". Is this correct?

Comment: Modified. I would like to have a solution for both of them. One output file with the results: if it starts with, and one with the results: if it ends with...

Comment: When i run `time bash_script` from Michael I do get `real 0m0.132s` and `time awk ...` I do get `real 0m0.003s`.  What is then faster?

Comment: How do you want the output sorted? Number of occurrences? Alphabetically by word in `a.txt`?

Comment: Descending sorted by the hits(starts or ends with) in two different files.

Comment: I have found this: Suppose I want to search for a whole word, not a part of a word?
          grep -w 'hello' *
searches only for instances of ‘hello’ that are entire words; it does not match ‘Othello’. For more control, use ‘\<’ and ‘\>’ to match the start and end of words. For example:

          grep 'hello\>' *
searches only for words ending in ‘hello’, so it matches the word ‘Othello’.

Comment: So it can be done with grep, but I don't know how to modify it to compare two files "-.-

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk` solution

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next} {for (i in a) {if ($0~i"$") {b[i]++;w[i]=w[i]?w[i] FS $0:$0}}} END {for (j in b) print b[j],j,w[j]}' a.txt b.txt
3 apple greenapple bigapple rottenapple
1 peach pinkpeach
```

It will not be simple or not possible at all to do this with `grep`

How does it work (it's not so complicated)?

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                        # Run this part for first file (a.txt) only
  a[$1]++                       # Store it in an array a
  next}                         # Skip to next record
  {                             # Run this part for file b.txt
  for (i in a) {                # Loop trough all data in array a
    if ($0~i"$") {              # Does b.txt have some from array a at the end of it?
      b[i]++                    # Yes , count it
      w[i]=w[i]?w[i] FS $0:$0   # and store the record it found it in in array w
      }
    }
  } 
END {                           # When both file has been read do the END part
  for (j in b)                  # Loop trough all element in array b and
    print b[j],j,w[j]}          # Print array b, index and array w
  ' a.txt b.txt                 # Read the two files
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. But please keep in mind, that 'potato' is not a hit, since 'xxlpotatoxxx' not ends in 'potato'. It contains, but not ends.

Comment: -What do I need to change if I would like to get the results in a txt file? (or in two files: one file for 'if it starts with' and 'if it ends with)

Comment: I have fixed the `potato`.  To store in a file just do `awk 'code' a.txt b.txt > result.txt`

Comment: It is up and running. If you can help me with the same but 'if it starts with', that would be nice.

Comment: Change the  `f=i"$"` to `f="^"i` and it will search for word starting with reference word.

Comment: +1, but the output sequence will be unpredictable due to looping through the hash keys with `for (j in b)`.

Comment: Can be easy sorted using `sort` and sort on number hits or text.  Can also be done within  `awk`, but it make it more complex and may reduce some speed.

Comment: I have found this: Suppose I want to search for a whole word, not a part of a word? grep -w 'hello' * searches only for instances of ‘hello’ that are entire words; it does not match ‘Othello’. For more control, use ‘\<’ and ‘\>’ to match the start and end of words. For example: grep 'hello\>' * searches only for words ending in ‘hello’, so it matches the word ‘Othello’. I have found this, so it can be done with grep, but I don't know how to modify it "-.- Your code is a solution, but still slow (100M vs 50K).

Comment: @fobiss: I doubt you'll find a faster solution than this using standard tools. Since you want to count matches _per search word_, you'd have to invoke `grep` for every line of `a.txt`: in other words: you'd end up running `grep` against `b.txt` 50K times.

Comment: @Jotne You can remove `f=i"$"` part by doing `if ($0 ~ i "$")`

Comment: +1: It was a good solution matched by a great explanation. That's how I was able to catch that superfluous statement. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that relies on `bash` and `grep` only. IMHO it is a little bit easier to understand than an `awk`-only approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set input parameters (usually a good idea than hardcoding them)
WORDFILE=a.txt
SEARCHFILE=b.txt

# Read 'a.txt' word by word (i.e. line by line)
while read word; do
  # Get numbers of hits
  num=`grep "$word\$" $SEARCHFILE | wc -l`

  # If no line matches in 'b.txt', skip this word
  if [ $num -eq 0 ]; then
    continue
  fi

  # Print number of hits and search word
  printf "%d $word" $num

  # Print all lines that match from file 'b.txt'
  for found in `grep "$word\$" $SEARCHFILE`; do
    printf " $found"
  done

  # Print newline
  printf "\n"
done < $WORDFILE
```

**EDIT**

If you want to store the results in a file, you can redirect the output of the above script the usual way, e.g.

```
./find_matching_ends.sh > matching_ends.txt
```

If you want to search for lines that *start* with the word, you need to change the `grep` pattern from `"$word\$"` to "^$word". If you want this search to happen simultaneously to the search for matching ends, you need to move the redirection above inside your script, e.g.

```
...
printf "%d $word" $num > matching_ends.txt
...
```

when you are searching for matching ends, and

```
...
printf "%d $word" $num > matching_starts.txt
...
```

when your are looking for lines that start with the search word.

Comment: -What do I need to change if I would like to get the results in a txt file? (or in two files: one file for 'if it starts with' and 'if it ends with)

Comment: Mine, of course :P Yeah, my solution is a hack, but one that's easier to understand, I think. If the OP is *really* concerned with speed, he should consider leaving the Bash realm and taking to another language. Although `awk` seems to be impressive, too.

Comment: I would not say this `bash `script is more easy to read than the `awk`, and its slower too. OP asks for speed

Comment: Correct, I would like to parse around 100M lines versus 50K.

Comment: I have found this: Suppose I want to search for a whole word, not a part of a word? grep -w 'hello' * searches only for instances of ‘hello’ that are entire words; it does not match ‘Othello’. For more control, use ‘\<’ and ‘\>’ to match the start and end of words. For example: grep 'hello\>' * searches only for words ending in ‘hello’, so it matches the word ‘Othello’. I have found this, so it can be done with grep, but I don't know how to modify it "-.- Your code is a solution, but still slow (100M vs 50K).

Comment: - It's better to use `grep -c` rather than piping to `wc -l`; that said, it's even better to avoid a separate `grep` invocation for counting the matches; instead, use:
`matches=$(grep "$word\$" "$SEARCHFILE" | tr '\n' ' '); num=$(set -- $matches; echo $#)`
- Re the last 2 `printf` snippets: the redirection should be `>>`, not `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to come up with a solution based on `Bash` that avoids `grep`. Instead it uses `for`-loops and arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set mode: start | end
mode="end"

# Read contents of input files into arrays - line by line
IFS=$'\n' read -d -r -a patterns < "$1"
IFS=$'\n' read -d -r -a targets < "$2"

# Bash 4 can use readarray
#readarray -t patterns < "$1"
#readarray -t targets < "$2"

# Alternatively use cat to get the contents into arrays (slower)
#patterns=($(cat $1))
#targets=($(cat $2))


# Iterate over both arrays to compare the strings with each other
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do

    # Setup a variable that counts the hits for each pattern
    hits_counter=0

    # Setup a variable that takes the matched strings for each pattern
    hits_match=""

    # Setup a regex pattern according to the user defined mode
    if [[ "$mode" == "start" ]]; then
        regex="^${pattern}"
    elif [[ "$mode" == "end" ]]; then
        regex="${pattern}$"
    fi

    for target in "${targets[@]}"; do

        # Use regex pattern matching
        if [[ "$target" =~ $regex ]]; then

            # If we detect a match increase the counter by 1
            (( hits_counter++ ))

            # If we detect a match write it to our hits_match variable and append a space
            hits_match+="${target} "
        fi
    done

    # Print a result for each pattern if we have at least one match
    if (( hits_counter > 0 )); then
        printf "%i %s %s\n" "$hits_counter" "$pattern" "$hits_match"
    fi
done
```

This gives the follwing result:

```
./filter a.txt b.txt
3 apple greenapple bigapple rottenapple
1 peach pinkpeach
```