# Grep ‘\<’ and ‘\>’ between two files

Tags: bash, grep

a.txt contains words, b.txt contains strings.

I would like to know how many string from b.txt starts or ends with the words from a.txt.

I have found this in GREP-s user manual: 
" Suppose I want to search for a whole word, not a part of a word?
          grep -w 'hello' *
searches only for instances of ‘hello’ that are entire words; it does not match ‘Othello’. For more control, use ‘\<’ and ‘>’ to match the start and end of words. For example:

```
      grep 'hello\>' *
```

searches only for words ending in ‘hello’, so it matches the word ‘Othello’."

but I dont know how to modify it to solve my problem.

Example: a.txt

```
apple
peach
potato
green
big
pink
```

b.txt

```
greenapple
bigapple
rottenapple
pinkpeach
xxlpotatoxxx
```

Output

ends.txt

```
3 apple greenapple bigapple rottenapple
1 peach pinkpeach
```

starts.txt

```
1 green greenapple
1 big bigapple
1 pink pinkpeach
```

I have received ideas here: 
[grep two files (a.txt, b.txt) - how many lines in b.txt starts (or ends) with the words from a.txt - output: 2 files with the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421188/grep-two-files-a-txt-b-txt-how-many-lines-in-b-txt-starts-or-ends-with-th?noredirect=1#comment34094624_22421188)

But since a.txt contains around 50K lines, and b.txt has more than 100M lines, I think, grep is the only solution.

Comment: You could write a simple bash script, that loops over `a.txt` and executes a grep for each line

Comment: Since you want to match against the _first_ and _last_ words respectively, you'd use `grep '^hello'` and `grep 'hello$'`, but since you want the occurrence count _per search word_, you'll still have to process the words in `a.txt` in a loop and thus invoke `grep` against the 100M-lines file 50K times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep two files (a.txt, b.txt) - how many lines in b.txt starts (or ends) with the words from a.txt - output: 2 files with the results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421188/grep-two-files-a-txt-b-txt-how-many-lines-in-b-txt-starts-or-ends-with-th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You best bet would be to write a script that would loop over every line of the file containing pattern and `grep` for the pattern in the other file:

The following would get the *startsWith* string:

```
while read -r w; do
  start=($(grep "^${w}" b.txt));
  (( ${#start[@]} != 0 )) && echo "${#start[@]} $w ${start[@]}";
done < a.txt
```

Execute it over your sample input, it'd yield:

```
1 green greenapple
1 big bigapple
1 pink pinkpeach
```

Similarly, you could write another one-liner that would get the *endsWith* strings:

```
while read -r w; do
  end=($(grep "${w}$" b.txt));
  (( ${#end[@]} != 0 )) && echo "${#end[@]} $w ${end[@]}";
done < a.txt
```

which would produce:

```
3 apple greenapple bigapple rottenapple
1 peach pinkpeach
```

---

EDIT: If you want to redirect the output to separate files, you could do both the parts in a single loop:

```bash
> startswith.txt     # Truncate the output files to begin with
> endswith.txt
while read -r w; do
  start=($(grep "^${w}" b.txt));
  (( ${#start[@]} != 0 )) && echo "${#start[@]} $w ${start[@]}" >> startswith.txt;
  end=($(grep "${w}$" b.txt));
  (( ${#end[@]} != 0 )) && echo "${#end[@]} $w ${end[@]}" >> endswith.txt;
done < a.txt
```

Comment: Hi, works like a charm, but still slow :( Would be faster without counting the hits? (only: found this, here, here here, etc, new line...)

Comment: @fobiss Given (1) the size of your input files, (2) constraints, i.e. getting count as well as `grep` output, I'd doubt if it could be any faster.  Moreover, it's rather custom in the sense that you want the output starting with the strings in one case and ending with in the other.

Comment: @fobiss The only way that you could make it speed up a whole lot would be if you don't want (1) the count, (2) the string that was being searched.

Comment: @fobiss, Better you split up the big file using `split`. Then, you will feel the speed of processing.

Comment: How can I forward the output to files instead of echo? I have reduced the size of the file, and now it is working way much better :))

Answer (score 3):

awk would be my first choice here. It should perform pretty well, even given your conditions.

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {word[$1]; next} 
    {
        for (w in word) {
            if ($1 ~ "^" w) starts[w] = starts[w] $1 " "
            if ($1 ~ w "$") ends[w] = ends[w] $1 " "
        }
    } 
    END {
        for (w in ends) {
            n = split(ends[w], a)
            print n, w, ends[w] > "ends.txt"
        }
        for (w in starts) {
            n = split(starts[w], a)
            print n, w, starts[w] > "starts.txt"
        }
    }
' a.txt b.txt
```

```
$ cat ends.txt
3 apple greenapple bigapple rottenapple
1 peach pinkpeach
$ cat starts.txt
1 pink pinkpeach
1 big bigapple
1 green greenapple
```

Comment: +1; perhaps trim the extra space at the end of the `start`, `end` array elements by using `starts[w] = starts[w] (starts[w] ? " " : "") $1`, ditto for `ends[w]`.

Comment: You could do that, but it is demonstrably not a problem. Also the [split](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bsplit_0028_0029_007d-function-1413) function trims leading and trailing whitespace when the field separator is " " (the default FS)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=a.txt
SEARCH=b.txt
OUTS=starts.txt
OUTE=ends.txt

while read line ; do
    echo -n "$line " >> "$OUTS"
    echo -n "$line " >> "$OUTE"
    grep "$line\>" "$SEARCH" | xargs >> "$OUTE"
    grep "\<$line" "$SEARCH" | xargs >> "$OUTS"
done < "$INPUT"
```

(This does not print the number of matches in front of the line)

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner

```
for a in `cat a.txt` ; do echo $a ; grep -c $a\\\>\\\|\\\<$a b.txt ; done
```

produces this output:

```
apple
3
peach
1
potato
0
green
1
big
1
pink
1
```

While it's not the pretty output that the alternatives produce, it's succinct and only executes grep once per line in `a.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your hint. It is also a solution, but I would like to know what and where have been found. :)